A game involving saying numbers coprime to all numbers said before.
This is a question from the LIMIT 2021 exam, Category C.

Sheldon and Leonard are playing a game. Sheldon has to select a number from $1$ to $20$ (inclusive). Leonard has to select a number that is co-prime to the same. Next, Sheldon has to choose a number which is coprime to all of the previously chosen ones. Assume Leonard is as smart as Sheldon when it comes to this game. So we assume optimal play on both ends. A player loses if he cannot choose any number which is coprime to all of the previously chosen ones.
In total, how many starting numbers are there for Sheldon to win and say "Bazinga!"? (TM Warner Bros.)

I tried to start with different numbers and see if the first player always wins in any case. For example, if the first player says $2$, the second player only has the odd numbers left. If he now says $15$, we are left with $1, 7, 11, 13, 17$ and $19$. As all six numbers are pairwise coprime, it does not matter what the moves are, the first player always loses.
In this manner, it seems like no matter what the first move is, the second player always has a move to win the game. I couldn't figure out the exact logic the rough idea I had involved grouping the numbers according to prime multiples, like- $(1), (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20), (3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18), (5, 10, 15, 20), (7, 14), (11), (13), (17)$ and $(19)$. I tried working on the idea that a move removes one or two groups. It seemed like whatever the first player says, the second player can always say a number such that we are left with even number of pairwise coprime numbers when it's the first player's move. Obviously, the first player always loses from here.
Is my answer correct? If yes, can somebody help in formulating a winning strategy?

Interesting problem! First you can try solving the easier version that only prime numbers from 1 to 19 are available. For this setup, which player always wins? After solving this, you can come to slightly more complicated current problem.

@MyMolecules as there are 8 primes, the second player should always win. I tried to extend this only by grouping multiples of each prime, but I don't know where to go from there.

Remember 1 is coprime to every integer, so 9 mutually coprime integers and first player always wins.

Sorry 1 was meant to be included. Now to attack current problem, each number is multiple of atmost 2 primes. Which ones? In how many ways can you keep number of mutually coprime integer groups odd?

By the way, this is a special case of a combinatorial game on graphs called Node Kayles; here the graph has vertices labeled 1 to 20 and an edge between two vertices when their labels have a common factor.

I think there is a condition missing that a number cannot be chosen again. Otherwise, each player can always choose 1, forever.


...grouping the numbers according to prime multiples, like- $(1), (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20), (3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18), (5, 10, 15, 20), (7, 14), (11), (13), (17)$ and $(19)$.

As will be shown, towards the end of my answer, the initial position is losing for Sheldon.  That is, Leonard can guarantee a win.

I think that the analysis of the original poster represents a very good beginning.
Initially, there are an odd number of groups.  So, if each player chooses a number that wipes out exactly one group, then the first player must win.
To say the same thing, in a different way, initially, the odd-even parity of the number of remaining groups, favors the first player.
I will use the phrase powerful number to represent any number whose prime factorization involves more than 1 prime.  So, $~10~$ is a powerful number, while $~8~$ is not a powerful number.
No powerful number, less than or equal to $~20~$ can wipe out more than $~2~$ groups.  This is because $~2 \times 3 \times 5 > 20.~$
I will use the phrase vulnerable group to represent any group that has more than one element.  Initially, there are exactly $~4~$ vulnerable groups.
The point of the phrase vulnerable group is that two vulnerable groups are subject to being wiped out simultaneously, which affects the odd-even parity of the number of groups remaining.
Before proceeding further, for illustrative purposes, I will examine why Sheldon=2, Leonard=15 loses for Sheldon.
The number $~2,~$ in addition to wiping out the $~2~$ group, converted the $~(7,14)~$ group to a group with no powerful number.
This is because the powerful number $~14~$ was eliminated.
In effect, the group $~(7,14),~$ while not wiped out, was converted from a vulnerable group to a group that is not vulnerable.
So, once Leonard simultaneously wiped out the $~3~$ and $~5~$ groups, Sheldon could not respond in kind.  That is, none of the remaining groups were vulnerable, so Sheldon could not remedy Leonard's  alteration of the odd-even parity of the number of groups remaining.
So, this was a mistake on the part of Sheldon.

Superficially, one would suppose that Sheldon's first number must  preserve the existence of exactly $~4~$ vulnerable groups.
Further, superficially, one would suppose that Sheldon must never do anything to affect the number of vulnerable groups until Leonard wipes out two of the vulnerable groups.
Once Leonard does this, Leonard has changed the odd-even parity of the number of remaining groups into his favor.
Then, superficially, one would suppose that Sheldon must then immediately wipe out the remaining $~2~$ vulnerable groups, which then restores the odd-even parity of the number of remaining groups.
So, superficially, this is Sheldon's basic winning strategy.  For illustrative purposes, I will now examine Scenario-1, which shows the value of such a superficial strategy.  Then, I will point out the flaw in such a strategy, and demonstrate that the initial position is losing for Sheldon.

Scenario-1 
Sheldon chooses $~1,~$ Leonard chooses $~15.$
Sheldon can then win with (for example) $~14.$
Suppose instead that then Sheldon chooses $~11,~$ instead of $~14.$
Then, Leonard, for his second choice can choose $~7.~$ This wipes out the $~7$-group but does not wipe out the $~2$-group.  Therefore, at this point it will be impossible for Sheldon to favorably restore the odd-even parity of the number of groups remaining.

Scenario-2 
Sheldon chooses $~1,~$ Leonard chooses $~10.$
Leonard has simultaneously wiped out the $~2$-group and the $~5$-group.  At this point, the odd-even parity of the number of groups remaining favors Leonard.
Further, Leonard has wiped out the number $~14.~$  So, the initially vulnerable group $~(7,14)~$ has lost its powerful number.  Therefore, it is impossible for Sheldon to subsequently simultaneously wipe out the $~3~$ group and the $~7~$ group.
Therefore, there is no way for Sheldon to favorably restore the odd-even parity of the number of groups remaining.

In order to complete the demonstration that the initially, the game is losing for Sheldon, I have to consider what happens if Sheldon's first number in some way affects the vulnerable groups.
If Sheldon's first choice wipes out two of the vulnerable groups, then Leonard can select a number that wipes out exactly one of the remaining vulnerable groups.
For example, if Sheldon chooses $~14,~$ then Leonard can choose $~3.$
If Sheldon wipes out exactly one of the vulnerable groups, when Leonard can wipe out exactly two of the three remaining vulnerable groups.  So, if Sheldon chooses $~7~$ or $~2,~$ then Leonard can choose $~15.~$
So, Sheldon loses because any first-number selection within the vulnerable groups, that Sheldon makes, will either wipe out $~1~$ or $~2~$ of the vulnerable groups.
